# Zod transform number to a new derived property

Tags: javascript, typescript, validation, zod

I just started using Zod to do typescript validation and I want to have an object from an API to have additional properties on the UI.

So the API will return an object such as:

```
 {
   id: '203923',
   name: 'best name',
   status: 1,
 }
```

I figured `.transform()` could do this but I haven't been able to figure it out.

and I want the frontend UI to have access to a different schema with a derived property like:

```
 {
   id: '203923',
   name: 'best name',
   status: 1,
   statusLabel: 'OK',
 }
```

Here is what I have tried.

```
export enum ReportMessageStatus {
    UNKNOWN = 0,
    OK = 1,
    UNREAD,
    DELETED,
}

export const ReportMessageSchema = z.object({
    id: z.string(),
    name: z.string(),
    status: z.nativeEnum(ReportMessageStatus),
    statusLabel: z.string().transform(value => transformStatus(value)),
});

function transformStatus(status) {
    switch (status) {
        case 1: 
            return "DELETED";
        case 2: 
            return "OK";
        default:
            return "UNKNOWN"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is a official recommended way, but you can transform the object to add a field

```
export const ReportMessageSchema = z
  .object({
    id: z.string(),
    name: z.string(),
    status: z.nativeEnum(ReportMessageStatus),
  })
  .transform((val) => ({ ...val, statusMessage: transformStatus(val.status) }));
```